# java web service cannot capture post parameter from jquery post

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, web-services

Client:

```
var data = "username=David";
$.post("/s/test", data, function(result) {
    alert(result);
});
```

Server:

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String test(@FormParam("username") String username) {
    return "Your username is " + username;
}
```

The username is always null from the $FormParam.

However, if post from form:

```
<form method="post" action="/s/test">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="David" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The value can be captured correct.

Really don't know why.

**New findings:
It happen to jquery 2.1, but 1.6 is ok.**

**Newer findings:
Use GF 3.1.2.2 will solve the issue as well, however, GF 4 has this issue.**

Comment: Probably the best start is to look in your browser's developer console to see which data is actually sent in both cases.

Comment: The path is different, you are posting to "/s/test" where as the controller shows '/test'

Comment: Thanks. There is an application path is "/s".